# If a curve $y=a\sqrt x +bx$ passes through $(1,2)$ and the area bounded by the curve, line $x=4$ and the $x$ axis

Tags: calculus, integration, area

The way solve this is by integrating the function from 0 to 4 ie
$$\int_0^4 f(x) =8$$ since the given curve clearly intersects $(0,0)$

But if try to find a point where $y=0$ by setting $y=0$

Then
$$0= a\sqrt x +bx$$
$$\sqrt x =\frac{-a}{b}$$ which doesn’t give $x=0$ since according to the answer, $a\not =0$

What is the reason behind this anomaly?

Comment: When you say $0 = a\sqrt x + bx \implies \sqrt x = \frac{-a}b$, did you divide by $\sqrt x$, which *could* be zero? You should instead write $\sqrt x(a + b\sqrt x) = 0$, which implies that $\sqrt x = 0$ or $\sqrt x = \frac{-a}b$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $x\geqslant0$ and that $b>0$, then\begin{align}a\sqrt x+bx=0&\iff\sqrt x\left(a+b\sqrt x\right)=0\\&\iff\sqrt x=0\vee a+b\sqrt x=0\\&\iff x=0\vee\sqrt x=-\frac ab.\end{align}